When using a JPanel with a horizontal scrollbar, the drawing inside the panel gets deformed when using the scrollbar
I have a scrollable jpanel inside a jframe.  In the jpanel I draw a ruler.  When I use the scrollbar to see more of the ruler, the ruler gets deformed.
enter image description here
Does anyone have an idea what could be te source of this problem?
